# React-Admin - How to log record data to the console?

Tags: react-admin

I'd like to know what are the data I'm working with, when using react-admin. (see them in the console to help debug)

For instance, when I'm working with a `List`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Datagrid, List, TextField } from 'react-admin';
import { ListProps } from '../../types/admin/ListProps';

const ProductList = (props: ListProps): JSX.Element => {
  console.log('ProductList.props', props);
  return (
    <List
      {...props}
      sort={{
        field: 'titleEN',
        order: 'DESC',
      }}
    >
      <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
        <TextField source="title" />
        <TextField source="titleEN" label={'Title (EN)'} />
        <TextField source="titleFR" label={'Title (FR)'} />
        {/*<ArrayField source="images"><SingleFieldList><ChipField source="id" /></SingleFieldList></ArrayField>*/}
        {/*<ReferenceArrayField source="imagesIds" reference="images"><TextField source="id" /></ReferenceArrayField>*/}
        <TextField source="customer.label" label={'Customer'} />
        <TextField source="price" />
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
  );
};

export default ProductList;
```

How can I do that? I haven't found anything in the official doc https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html

Answer (score 1):

This kind of logging can be displayed through the Data Provider. See https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html

For instance, with https://github.com/marcantoine/ra-data-graphql-prisma data provider, one such implementation could be https://github.com/UnlyEd/ra-data-graphql-prisma/commit/4031c5c3f2e97c479a9714df56da06653a908444

Comment: The link to your commit view is private. Mind if be able to share it?
NOTE: I did not consider downvoting because I'm sure the link has the answer.

Comment: I edited, thanks for letting me know, I think I moved the repo to my company account since then.